# Download Picture in Android at back-end of application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am working on an application where multi user attract with a single user that is currently login on my application,Here I need to download the picture using URLConnection,I send request to server and server response me picture data in form of stream then using URLConnection object I get Input Stream with data that is working fine.now here I need to handle the multi downloading of pictures at back-end,like if user B,C,D sending me pictures how I can download these at back-end ? means how I can Sync downloading process at back-end of my application ? Here I need to do the Async Task ? it will do multi threading for handling different request at same time ? 
thanks in advance . . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use AsyncTask also for this. Its better if you can use a service which downloads all the Images in the background using the asyncTask. If you want an example for this, please [click here for more info](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service).

Answer (score 0):

Use [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).